# New headlines in org-mode don't always appear on a new line

Tags: org-mode

When the point is at the end of a headline in org-mode and I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (bound to `org-meta-return`), the new headline often starts on the *same* line instead of on a new one. It happens frequently, but far from always and seemingly at random. I'm not able to reproduce this from a clean init, but I have no idea which package or variable is causing the problem.

If you have encountered this or have any ideas how to fix it, please let me know because it's driving me mad.

Comment: Report what you see on doing `C-h k M-RET` the next time it behaves that way. Once it starts behaving that way, does it consistently stay that way for the rest of the emacs session?

Comment: It says it's bound to `org-meta-return`, explaining that it "Calls `org-insert-heading` or `org-table-wrap-region`, depending
on context.  See the individual commands for more information."  That seems normal? But in the help for `org-insert-heading` it doesn't even seem to mention how it is supposed to behave when the point is at the end of heading.

Comment: Please report bugs with reproducible receipts for triggering the error on the org mailing list.